# Static method with Spring bean.

Tags: java, spring, static, javabeans

```
public class QuestionStaticObject {
    private static String staticprefix;
    private static BeanFactory factory;

    @Value("${account.prefix}")
    public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        staticprefix = prefix;
    }

    public static String getPrefix() {
        return staticprefix;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setFactory(BeanFactory f) {
        factory = f;
    }

    public static BeanFactory getFactory() {
        return factory;
    }

    public static String foo1(String id) {
        String uuid = getPrefix() + id + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        return uuid;
    }

    public static boolean foo2() throws GFMException {  
        OtherObject obj = getFactory().getBean(OtherObject.class);
        return obj.foo1();
    }
}
```

My Team's a crew write java code above that. But I think that code is very dangerous because if spring bean's loading is late, then static method will reference of null factory or null 'staticprefix'.

How do you think about that?

Comment: Probably this question belongs more on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Even if I think writing static stuff like this is broken, I don't think this specific code is dangerous.

The setPrefix will be called just after the object instanciation, so there is no risk of NPE.

The object is by default a singleton. So there is also no risk of concurrent call.
But it is bad code design.